# It is possible to obtain scoped elevation within a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm relatively unfamiliar with account aspects of C#/.Net, and what I'm trying to achieve is something along the lines of:

```cs
    public void execute_w_elevation(Action action)
    {    
      var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
      if (!principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
      {
        // v prompt the user for permission and get elevation, somehow
        var token = have_user_approve_elevation(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid);
        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(token, action);
      }
      else
      {
        action();
      }
    }
```

Is this a viable path - I couldn't find any way to get from the WellKnownSid or BuiltInRole.Administrator to a SafeAccessTokenHandle, and other documentation seems to suggest you're expected to ask the user for a username and password, which would seem moot since they're already ... them?

Comment: Elevating applications requires a process restart, you can't use an existing process nor delegated Win32 token for elevation.

Comment: Create a manifest and ask for `level='highestAvailable'`. When your program starts, regular uses will get a normal token, while admins will get an _elevated_ token. But as @dai points out, this is all sorted out before your code starts. Search for (uac manifest) to find docs on this

Comment: @Dai So is elevation different than identity? If I had them enter the admin username/password, and used a WindowsImpersonationContext/RunImpersonated, it would be a different user but still not elevated?

Comment: Before you are a guru on Windows security and identities, try to use the simplest approach that split non-admin and admin code to separate processes, so that the non-admin process can execute the admin process on demand and trigger elevation only when necessary. Other approaches are either too difficult to understand or require too many pieces of code to tie together.

Comment: @LexLi The project that inspired this question began as simple powershell automation, carefully compartmentalized modules, classes, and steps, all of which translated beautifully into a C# evolution aside from two contact points where elevation *may* be required. I already have that solved, but elevated child processes have plenty of drawbacks - your code can't stop them, job_object_limits won't reap them, they can't see the same subst mappings, ...